# Combo box considerando a escolha anterior

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma duvida de como fazer um combo box relacionado na escolha anterior do input, por exemplo:

Se escolher SP irei ter três opções na lista Sorocaba, Boituva, Tatuí

Mas que continue montando o link como abaixo:

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="montadora" type="text" value="montadora"></input>
  <input id="modelo" type="text" value="modelo"></input>
  <input id="ano" type="text" value="ano"></input>
  <INPUT type="reset" name="b2" value="Limpar">
  <INPUT type="submit" name="b1" value="Pesquisar" onClick="location.href='http://www.rs1.com.br/'+document.getElementById('montadora').value+'/'+document.getElementById('modelo').value+'/'+document.getElementById('ano').value">
</div>
```

Lembrando que, ao invés de o usuário digitar, ele escolhe o valor no dropdown.

Comment: Nenhum que simule o que eu preciso, mais obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se entendi direito sua dúvida, você quer um formulário cujos valores dos campos `select` sejam criados dinâmicamente. Se for isso, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```js
var arr_cidades = {
  sp: ["Sorocaba", "Boituva", "Tatuí"],
  rj: ["Uma cidade do Rio", "Outra cidade"]
}

function escolha() {
  var estado = document.querySelector("#estado");
  var cidade = document.querySelector("#cidade");

  cidade.disabled = false;

  cidade.innerHTML = "";

  switch (estado.value) {
    case "sp":
      for (i in arr_cidades.sp) {
        cidade.innerHTML += "<option>" + arr_cidades.sp[i] + "</option>"
      };
      break;
    case "rj":
      for (i in arr_cidades.rj) {
        cidade.innerHTML += "<option>" + arr_cidades.rj[i] + "</option>"
      };
      break;
    default:
      cidade.innerHTML += "<option>- Selecione uma cidade -</option>";
      cidade.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<span>Estado</span>
<br>
<select id='estado' onchange="escolha()">
  <option value=''>- Selecione um Estado -</option>
  <option value='sp'>SP</option>
  <option value='rj'>RJ</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<span>Cidade</span>
<br>
<select id='cidade' disabled="true">
  <option value=''>- Selecione uma Cidade -</option>
</select>
```

Como você pode ver, criei um array com as cidades, e quando o usuário selecionar uma determinada opção a função `escolha()` será chamada. Nessa função ocorre um `switch case` que avaliará qual foi a opção escolhida no campo anterior e de acordo com isso selecionará as cidades no array, depois disso cria a opções no próximo campo.

***Obs.:*** Caso queira fazer um dropdown, usando `ul` e `li`, ou `div`, como um menu mesmo, é só adaptar um pouquinho o código, fazendo com que no loop `for` do `switch case` seja gerado um `<a href="#"></a>` ao invés de `option`.

Espero ter ajudado.